# C# shifting the focus in chart on last samples

Tags: c#, charts, focus, zooming

I have a datatable with values (first column is the timeline (X axis) and the second are the values). This datatable is continiously updating and I need to show only last few 100 samples so Im using

Im periodically shifting the focus

```
        chartGraf.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = double.NaN;
        chartGraf.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = double.NaN;
        chartGraf.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
        chartGraf.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
        chartGraf.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(actual_time -time_window_size, actual_time);
```

but unfortunately `chartGraf.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom` is focusing according to the row in datatable but not the actual value in the row fox X axis.

Fof example when the `chartGraf.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(34, 64);` is display values in range of 3400-6400 instead of 34-64 because of there are values 100 in row 0, 200 in row 1, 300 in row 3 etc. What I need is to focus according to the actual alue in the X axis, but not its index of the row in data table.

Thanks

[image: Example]